# Analyzing the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{t}f_1(t,\tau)f_2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.$

Tags: limits, indefinite-integrals

I am studying the function $$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f_1(t,\tau)f_2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.$$ I known that the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f_1(t,\tau)=g(\tau)$ exists and is finite. Is it possible to prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(\tau)f_2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$ under the assumption that this limit exists?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436168/interchanging-limit-and-integration-when-bounds-of-integration-depend-on-a-param Maybe this can help?

Comment: Thank you for the Link. In the link it the authors claim the following:  Now it is easy to prove that,
$$
\lim_{t \to T}\;
\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} p(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}x= \int_a^b p(x,T) \, \mathrm{d} x
$$
with $p$ a polynomial and $a$ and $b$ continuous functions. How to prove this?

Comment: Moreover, the proof is based on the approximation of the integrand by a polynomial and applying the Stone-Weiherstrass Theorem. This theorem is however only valid for closed intervals. Since the interval here is infinite, it can not be immediately applied. Can  ageneralized Fourier expansion based on orthogonal polynomials be used?